# jQuery 2.0 dropped support for IE6/7/8, so how long will the 1.x branch be maintained?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jquery-2.0

jQuery 2.0 has just been released and completely dropped support for Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 [[more...](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)]. Currently [April 2013] the 1.9.x branch is still maintained, and probably will receive some improvements and bugfixes [1.10 will come!], but sure not for long. jQuery announced that it is possible to use 2.0 and 1.9 on the same page, but sooner or later this branch will be dropped.

With a global market share of 6-7% [[more...](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp)], in some countries even 50% (China etc. [[more...](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)]), the IE8/7/6 group is still a big thing on the web, and a lot of huge old-school companies still use them in-house, with no plans to update. The reality is: Even in 2015 there will be an economically significant amount of IE6/7/8 users [according to burndown calculations]. And the often-heard argument "Let's drop those users" is not a good one, in a professional corporate environment no sales person would ever agree to this, not even if the percentage of users is 0.5%! It's a pity, but IE8/7 will still be important to a lot of frontend developers in 2013, 2014 and 2015, for people mainly working with clients from asia etc. probably even longer (!).

**So my question is: Is there an official statement that shows the long-term-service roadmap for the jQuery 1.x branch ?**

*Note: I asked the offical jQuery team, but haven't got an answer yet.*

Comment: Why the hell are people 1. downvoting and 2. closing this ? Sorry people, but this is sooooooo wrong... Yes, it's not a "why does my code not work"-question, but it's an essential question that affects nearly every frontend developer in the world. So why are people seriously calling this "off topic" ?

Comment: ANSWER: As this might be interesting for other people too: The way to go here is to simply stay on the "current" version if jQuery. If your client insists on IE67/8 support, then you simply cannot use jQuery 2.0+ features, which is totally okay i think.

Answer (score 3):

There does not yet appear to be an official statement showing the long-term-service roadmap, but there has been a promise that it will not be dropped anytime soon. According to their [official statement](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/):

"The jQuery team will continue to support both the jQuery 1.x and 2.x lines simultaneously **for as long as those older versions of IE are still a factor**... We fully expect that most Internet web sites may continue to use jQuery 1.x for quite a while, as long as older versions of IE still comprise a large proportion of web surfers. And so the jQuery team will also continue to support both the jQuery 1.x and 2.x lines"

Comment: According to a comment on this vulnerability, jQuery 1.x and 2.x are no longer maintained, and they recommend moving to 3.x to mitigate: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432#issuecomment-290983196